# How to split string separated by | character

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have input string in the following format 
`first|second|third|<forth>|<fifth>|$sixth` I want to split this string into an array of string with value [first,second,third,,,$sixth]. I am using following code to split the string but that is not working. please help me.

```
public String[] splitString(String input){
String[] resultArray = input.split("|")
return resultArray;
    }
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape `|` using backslash as it is a special character. This should work:

```
String[] resultArray = input.split("\\|")
```

Comment: I don't think that is true. I'll research it, and undo the downvote if it is.

Comment: @tbodt I believe it is true!

Comment: I think it *is* true.

Comment: It means OR in regular expressions.

Comment: Take a look at this [table of escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I give up. It is a special char in regular expressions.

Comment: @JunedAhsan, thanks for your hints but the correct method is `input.split("\\|")` thanks again

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Okay, you are right. Apart from that, Juned Ahsan was correct.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Didn't say he wasn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a meta character meaning it represents something else in regex. Considering `split` takes regex as an argument, it interprets the argument using regex. You need to "escape" all of the meta characters by placing a `\\` before it. In your case, you would do:

```
String[] resultArray = input.split("\\|");
```